# agda return the even number index of the list

Tags: agda

The code is:

```
filter-pos : {A : Set} →  A → (ℕ → ) →  A 
filter-pos = {!!}

filter-pos-test : filter-pos ('a' :: 'b' :: 'c' :: 'd' :: 'e' :: 'f' :: []) is-even ≡ 'a' :: 'c' :: 'e' :: []
filter-pos-test = refl
```

My thought is to use `nth` to output `nth` index, use `map` function to make them into a list, and if it's a even number `n`, it will return. However, that is not working correctly.

Can someone let me know how I should go about solving this? I think it will be helpful to write a help function to solve the problem.

Answer (score 2):

I'll be using the standard library.

One dumb solution is to zip a list with indices of elements, use the usual `filter` and then remove the indices. E.g.

```
'a' :: 'b' :: 'c' :: 'd' :: 'e' :: 'f' :: []
```

becomes

```
('a', 0) :: ('b', 1) :: ('c', 2) :: ('d', 3) :: ('e', 4) :: ('f', 5) :: []
```

`filter (is-even ∘ snd)` returns

```
('a', 0) :: ('c', 2) :: ('e', 4) :: []
```

and `map fst` results in

```
'a' :: 'c' :: 'e' :: []
```

A more natural solution is to traverse a list and increment a counter on each recursive call:

```
filter-pos : {A : Set} → List A → (ℕ → Bool) → List A 
filter-pos {A} xs p = go 0 xs where
  go : ℕ -> List A -> List A
  go i  []      = []
  go i (x ∷ xs) = if p i then x ∷ r else r where
    r = go (suc i) xs
```

Here `i` is the index of an element. However now whenever you need to prove something about `filter-pos`, you'll need to prove a lemma about `go` first, because it's `go` does the actual job, while `filter-pos` is just a wrapper around it. An idiomatic solution looks like this:

```
filter-pos : {A : Set} → List A → (ℕ → Bool) → List A 
filter-pos  []      p = []
filter-pos (x ∷ xs) p = if p 0 then x ∷ r else r where
  r = filter-pos xs (p ∘ suc)
```

Here instead of incrementing a counter we adjust a predicate and compose it with `suc`. So on a first element we check whether `p 0` is true, on a second element we check whether `(p ∘ suc) 0` (which immediately reduces to `p 1`) is true, on a third element we check whether `(p ∘ suc ∘ suc) 0` (which immediately reduces to `p 2`) is true and so on. I.e. this is the same solution as with a counter, but uses only one function.

The last version also can be tuned to work with `Fin` instead of `ℕ`

```
filter-pos-fin : {A : Set} → (xs : List A) → (Fin (length xs) → Bool) → List A 
filter-pos-fin  []      p = []
filter-pos-fin (x ∷ xs) p = if p zero then x ∷ r else r where
  r = filter-pos-fin xs (p ∘ suc)
```

Comment: FYI, as a working functional programmer, I find the `map snd . filter (p . fst) . zip [0..]` solution much more "natural" than the second one.

Comment: @Cactus, it's unnatural in a formal setting, because there you have to either inline `zip [0..]` (which will eventually give you the second solution, only more verbose) or use a coinductive type to represent `[0..]`. And your definition is not perfect even in a practical programming setting as it doesn't fuse properly.